# Why the scrollbar doesn't reach the end when it is link with other scrollbar by javascript formula?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I actually work on a code with mutliple scrollbars and they are all linked so if you move one the 2 others will move proportionally, I said proportionally because they don't have the same width. It's pretty interesting but it doesn't work very well because sometimes(always for now) the scroller doesn't reach the end of the scrollbar...

So my question is: How can I modify my code to reach the end of the scrollbar with the scroller ?
PS: you have to hover the green div to display the third scrollbar.
Clues: I think the source of the problem is directly linked with the functions that link the scrollbars between them, but I can't figure out what's wrong with them...

Here's the code:

```js
let w_mob_len = getComputedStyle(document.getElementById('w_mob_child'), null).width.replace("px", "") - getComputedStyle(document.getElementById('w_mob'), null).width.replace("px", "");
let w_top_len = getComputedStyle(document.getElementById('w_top_child'), null).width.replace("px", "") - getComputedStyle(document.getElementById('w_top'), null).width.replace("px", "");
let w_tab_len = getComputedStyle(document.getElementById('w_tab_child'), null).width.replace("px", "") - getComputedStyle(document.getElementById('w_tab'), null).width.replace("px", "");

function move_scrollbar_mobile() {
  let wrap_mob = document.getElementById("w_mob");
  let wrap_top = document.getElementById("w_top");
  let wrap_tab = document.getElementById("w_tab");
  wrap_top.scrollLeft = wrap_mob.scrollLeft * w_top_len / w_mob_len;
  wrap_tab.scrollLeft = wrap_mob.scrollLeft * w_tab_len / w_mob_len;
}

function move_scrollbar_top() {
  let wrap_mob = document.getElementById("w_mob");
  let wrap_top = document.getElementById("w_top");
  let wrap_tab = document.getElementById("w_tab");
  wrap_mob.scrollLeft = wrap_top.scrollLeft * w_mob_len / w_top_len;
  wrap_tab.scrollLeft = wrap_top.scrollLeft * w_tab_len / w_top_len;
}

function move_scrollbar_table() {
  let wrap_mob = document.getElementById("w_mob");
  let wrap_top = document.getElementById("w_top");
  let wrap_tab = document.getElementById("w_tab");
  wrap_mob.scrollLeft = wrap_tab.scrollLeft * w_mob_len / w_tab_len;
  wrap_top.scrollLeft = wrap_tab.scrollLeft * w_top_len / w_tab_len;
}

function disp_scroll_mob() {
  document.getElementById("w_mob").style.display = "inline-block";
}

function hide_scroll_mob() {
  let w_flo = document.getElementById("w_flo");
  w_flo.addEventListener("mouseleave", function() {
    document.getElementById("w_mob").style.display = "none";

  });
}

function disp_scroll_mob_alt() {
  let w_mob = document.getElementById("w_mob");
  w_mob.addEventListener("mouseenter", function() {
    document.getElementById("w_mob").style.display = "inline-block";
  })
}
```

```css
.wrapper_top,
.wrapper_table {
  width: 300px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

.wrapper_mobile {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  top: 10%;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  display: none;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: red;
  z-index: 2;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.wrapper_float {
  width: 100%;
  height: 60%;
  top: 20%;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #88FF88;
  z-index: 1;
}

.wrapper_top {
  height: 20px;
}

.wrapper_table {
  height: 200px;
}

.child_top {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 20px;
}

.child_mobile {
  width: 300px;
  height: 20px;
}

.search_table {
  table-layout: fixed;
}

th {
  font-size: 15px;
  background: #66C2E0;
}

th {
  min-width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper_mobile" id="w_mob" onscroll="move_scrollbar_mobile()" onmouseover="">
  <div class="child_mobile" id="w_mob_child">

  </div>
</div>

<div class="wrapper_top" id="w_top" onscroll="move_scrollbar_top()">
  <div class="child_top" id="w_top_child">

  </div>
</div>


<div class="wrapper_table" id="w_tab" onscroll="move_scrollbar_table()" onmouseout="hide_scroll_mob()">
  <div class="wrapper_float" id="w_flo" onmouseover="disp_scroll_mob()" onmouseout="disp_scroll_mob_alt()">

  </div>
  <table class="search_table" id="w_tab_child">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th>Col1</th>
        <th>Col2</th>
        <th>Col3</th>
        <th>Col4</th>
        <th>Col5</th>
        <th>Col6</th>
        <th>Col7</th>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the main problem is, your triggering the scroll events across all three divs and depending on which is called last, this will effect the end position of all divs.

I've tried adding a small delay below, it's not production code but should give you an idea of how to reduce the jankiness.

```js
const wrap_mob = document.getElementById("w_mob");
const wrap_top = document.getElementById("w_top");
const wrap_tab = document.getElementById("w_tab");

let lastScrollMob, lastScrollTop, lastScrollTable = 0;
let scrolling = false;
wrap_mob.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
  lastScrollMob = wrap_mob.scrollLeft;
  if (!scrolling) {
    window.requestAnimationFrame(function() {
      scrollMobile(lastScrollMob);
      scrolling = false;
    });
    scrolling = true;
  }
});
wrap_top.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
  lastScrollTop = wrap_top.scrollLeft;
  if (!scrolling) {
    window.requestAnimationFrame(function() {
      scrollTop(lastScrollTop);
      scrolling = false;
    });
    scrolling = true;
  }
});
wrap_tab.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
  lastScrollTable = wrap_tab.scrollLeft;
  if (!scrolling) {
    window.requestAnimationFrame(function() {
      scrollTable(lastScrollTable);
      scrolling = false;
    });
    scrolling = true;
  }
});

function scrollMobile (amount) {
  let percent = (amount / w_mob_len) * 100;
  wrap_top.scrollLeft = (w_top_len / 100) * percent;
  wrap_tab.scrollLeft = (w_tab_len / 100) * percent;
}
function scrollTop (amount) {
  let percent = (amount / w_top_len) * 100;
  wrap_mob.scrollLeft = (w_mob_len / 100) * percent;
  wrap_tab.scrollLeft = (w_tab_len / 100) * percent;
}
function scrollTable (amount) {
  let percent = (amount / w_tab_len) * 100;
  wrap_mob.scrollLeft = (w_mob_len / 100) * percent;
  wrap_top.scrollLeft = (w_top_len / 100) * percent;
}

let w_mob_len = getComputedStyle(document.getElementById('w_mob_child'), null).width.replace("px", "") - getComputedStyle(wrap_mob, null).width.replace("px", "");

let w_top_len = getComputedStyle(document.getElementById('w_top_child'), null).width.replace("px", "") - getComputedStyle(wrap_top, null).width.replace("px", "");

let w_tab_len = getComputedStyle(document.getElementById('w_tab_child'), null).width.replace("px", "") - getComputedStyle(wrap_tab, null).width.replace("px", "");

function disp_scroll_mob() {
  document.getElementById("w_mob").style.display = "inline-block";
}

function hide_scroll_mob() {
  let w_flo = document.getElementById("w_flo");
  w_flo.addEventListener("mouseleave", function() {
    console.log("hide");
    document.getElementById("w_mob").style.display = "none";
  });
}

function disp_scroll_mob_alt() {
  let w_mob = document.getElementById("w_mob");
  w_mob.addEventListener("mouseenter", function() {
    document.getElementById("w_mob").style.display = "inline-block";
  })
}
```

```css
.wrapper_top,
.wrapper_table {
  width: 300px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

.wrapper_mobile {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  top: 10%;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  display: none;

  background-color: red;
  z-index: 2;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.wrapper_float {
  width: 100%;
  height: 60%;
  top: 20%;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #88FF88;
  z-index: 1;
}

.wrapper_top {
  height: 20px;
}

.wrapper_table {
  height: 200px;
}

.child_top {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 20px;
}

.child_mobile {
  width: 300px;
  height: 20px;
}

.search_table {
  table-layout: fixed;
}

th {
  font-size: 15px;
  background: #66C2E0;
}

th {
  min-width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper_mobile" id="w_mob">
  <div class="child_mobile" id="w_mob_child"></div>
</div>

<div class="wrapper_top" id="w_top">
  <div class="child_top" id="w_top_child"></div>
</div>

<div class="wrapper_table" id="w_tab" onmouseout="hide_scroll_mob()">
  <div class="wrapper_float" id="w_flo" onmouseover="disp_scroll_mob()" onmouseout="disp_scroll_mob_alt()">
  </div>
  <table class="search_table" id="w_tab_child">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th>Col1</th>
        <th>Col2</th>
        <th>Col3</th>
        <th>Col4</th>
        <th>Col5</th>
        <th>Col6</th>
        <th>Col7</th>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: This is great, but there is a tiny amount of pixel that blocked the scroller to reach the end of the red scrollbar. but it's work pretty well on the other scrollbar, I don't know why the moving div cause problem...

Comment: Hey @bosskay972 - this is because of the padding for `wrapper_mobile`. Have a look now, I've updated again.

Comment: Incredible ! It works perfectly as I expect ! Just a little request: delete the console.log("hide") because we can't see clearly the result. Apart from that it's perfect !

Comment: Good to hear (: